# Sizing cache in Internal Memory

Tags: android, caching, memory, storage, internal

I'm looking to use internal memory to store my cache files instead of external storage. The main reason is that I need my app to function even if external storage is shared with a computer.

The dev docs say "You should always maintain the cache files yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space consumed, such as 1MB.".
Is this text just too old? Devices I've seen in the last 12 months have hundreds of megabytes of internal memory (tablets can have gigabytes - and I'm not confusing different types of storages here).

Even a decent thumbnail on a large screen can easily be around 20-30kbytes and you can display 50 thumbnails on the screen at once. If you do some scrolling, you'll be using way more than 1MB.

Do you guys think I can go with let's say 10 megs (not going higher, maintaining it properly)?
Do you know about any Google App or other popular app that maintains way larger cache in internal storage than 1MB?

Edit:
I'm asking about this type of memory:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Is it possible that the text was talking ab actual hardware cache memory? 1-2MB is a decent amount for cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Devices I've seen in the last 12 months have hundreds of megabytes of internal memory (tablets can have gigabytes - and I'm not confusing different types of storages here).

Newer devices have more storage. Older devices have less storage. By only supporting newer Android OS updates, you will tend to have devices with more internal storage. And, starting with Android 3.0, internal and external storage work from the same space (external storage is effectively a subdirectory within internal storage) and external storage should always be available.

> Do you guys think I can go with let's say 10 megs (not going higher, maintaining it properly)?

On Android 3.0 and higher, sure.

On Android 2.3 and higher, maybe.

On Android 2.2 and lower, I wouldn't.

And, in any of those cases:

- Allow the user to configure the cache size
- Honor `ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW` broadcasts to trim your cache

Comment: Hi CommonsWare,
Thanks for your reply. I think you may have misunderstood me.
I'm talking abount internal storage which is application private and is not accessible for anyone else unless the device is rooted.

Comment: @user289463: No, I understood you. My answer still stands.

Comment: My comment was quite poor and faulty, sorry.
A better attempt:

Terminology I'm using:
Internal Memory: App private storage, very limited in the old days
Phone Storage: HTC's terminology for their embedded "flash drives"
External Storage: Android's terminology for the one and only storage which is not the Internal Memory. (Google doesn't officially support OEMs storage hacks unless they add it as a subdirectory under the existing External Storage location)

So, I'm not looking to use the external storage.

Comment: Also about "external storage should always be available":
On the Xoom it's like this, yes. ..but take a look at the HTC Flyer with Honeycomb. They managed to hack back the original shared/mounted exclusive limitation back into Honeycomb..

Comment: @user289463: I still understood you. My answer still stands. You asked whether you can use 10MB of cache storage, and my answer is that I would not do that on Android 2.2 or less, but on Android 3.0 and higher it should not be a problem. What part of that answer is too complicated?

Comment: CommonsWare: I don't understand the first part of your answer, so I'm not sure if you answered the right thing in the 2nd part.
The first part's problem: You say external is a subdirectory under internal. I don't understand this, as Internal is app-private and is not even visible from a file browser for example. External is public storage, so if it is a subdirectory under intental, it wouldn't be visible. Am I missing something?
Also, I don't know how does the "external should be always available" part relate to my question. (And it unfortunately doesn't even help on a HTC Flyer for example.)

Comment: @user289463: "Am I missing something?" -- in most operating systems written in the past two decades, a subdirectory can have different permissions than its parent directory.

Comment: CommonsWare: Good point. I still think the answer is mixing a couple of unrelated things, but I don't want to drive you crazy, so I just accept it and do my research ;)